# Paypal purchase not happening in HTML with ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, paypal

I have the little Paypal window working in the sandbox and production mode.  The onAuthorize function gets called and my message window pops up thanking you for the purchase and giving the purchased credits to the customer.

```
    paypal.Button.render({

        <% if (useBankAccount) { %>
            env: 'production', // Or 'sandbox', 'production'
        <% } else { %>
            env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox', 'production'
        <% }%>

        client: {
        sandbox: 'Axxx',
            production: 'Axxx'
        },
        commit: true,

        style: {
            size: 'responsive',
                color: 'gold',
                shape: 'pill',
                label: 'pay'
        },

        payment: function (data, actions) {

            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: { total: currentPayment, currency: 'USD' }

                        }
                    ]
                 }
            });
         },


        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {

            if (window.ga) { // Google Analytics
                window.ga('send', 'event', 'Credits', 'Purchase', 'Payment', currentPayment);
                window.ga('send', 'event', 'Credits', 'Purchase', 'Credits', currentCredits);
            }

            document.getElementById("<%= PurchaseDone.ClientID %>").value = "Yes";
            document.getElementById("<%= PurchaseAmount.ClientID %>").value = currentPayment;
            TheForm.submit(); 
        },

        onCancel: function (data, actions) {
            OpenMessageWindow("The payment was cancelled.");
        },


        onError: function (err) {
            var result = err.message.toString().indexOf("Amount cannot be zero")

            if (result > 0) {
                OpenMessageWindow('Payment Error: The purchase amount must be more than zero');
                return;
            }

            OpenMessageWindow('Payment Error:<br/>' + err.message)
        }

    }, '#paypal-button');
```

Looking the data passed into OnAuthorize()

```
{paymentToken: "EC-xxx", 
orderID: "EC-xxx", 
payerID: "FTxxx", 
paymentID: "PAY-xxx", 
intent: "sale", …}

intent:"sale" orderID:"EC-xxx"
payerID:"FTxxx"
paymentID:"PAY-xxx"
paymentToken:"EC-xxx"
returnUrl:
"https://www.paypal.com/?paymentId=PAY-0Kxxx&token=EC-xx&PayerID=FTxxx"
__proto__ :Object
```

actions is

```
{close: ƒ, redirect: ƒ, payment: {…}, order: {…}, restart: ƒ, …}
```

To see those values, I commented out the TheForm.Submit(), which could have been the problem but the payment still did not happen.

The problem is, in production, the customer purchase does not happen. The customer (me) logs into their Paypal account, presses Pay Now, the window disappears calling onAuthorize.

No payment registers on the customer account. No payment transaction happens and my software gives the credits for free.

Ideas? What can I look at?  Paypal telephone support does not know anything about development.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: [Follow the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/add-paypal-button/) - you're missing the [payment setup](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/set-up-a-payment/) step altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call actions.payment.execute() in the onAuthorize callback. It causes a second busy indicator that does the payment. It's like the onAuthorize says the user accepts, now do you accept?

Now, this is my working code.

```
        paypal.Button.render({

        <% if (useBankAccount) { %>
            env: 'production', // Or 'sandbox', 'production'
        <% } else { %>
            env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox', 'production'
        <% }%>

        client: {
            sandbox: 'xxx',
            production: 'xxx'
        },
        commit: true,

        payment: function (data, actions) {

            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: { total: currentPayment, currency: 'USD' }

                        }
                    ]
                 }
            });
         },


        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {

            return actions.payment.execute().then(function (payment) {
                // setup the data to post
                TheForm.submit(); 
            });
         },

        onCancel: function (data, actions) {
            OpenMessageWindow("The payment was cancelled.");
        },


        onError: function (err) {
            var result = err.message.toString().indexOf("Amount cannot be zero")

            if (result > 0) {
                OpenMessageWindow('Payment Error: The purchase amount must be more than zero');
                return;
            }
            OpenMessageWindow('Payment Error:<br/>' + err.message)
        }

    }, '#paypal-button');
```

I added two things from the PayPal example to get it working.

The "commit: true," is needed to change the Continue button to Pay Now. Unbelievably, the default is to have a button called Continue that pays.

The second is calling actions.payment.execute() in onAuthorize.  Not something you could figure out except by being told.

I am quite incredulous that the PayPal example does not include these two items providing an example that simply does not work. AND you don't know about it until you test a live purchase, sandbox seems fine.

Additionally, Stack Overflow is PayPal's development support, why was this question never answered? I actually found the solution to the problem on a web page explaining how bad PayPal is compared to Stripe. The page gave a nice example of the complicated PayPal code that had the missing function call.